# Spark structured streaming exactly once - Not achieved - Duplicated events

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I am using Spark Structured Streaming to consume events from Kafka and upload them to S3.

Checkpoints are committed on S3:

```
DataFrameWriter<Row> writer = input.writeStream()
           .format("orc")
           .trigger(ProcessingTime(config.getProcessingTime()))
           .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
           .option("truncate", false)           
           .option("checkpointLocation", "s3://bucket1")
           .option("compression", "zlib")
           .option("path", "s3://bucket2");
```

The offsets are committed to Kafka via `StreamingQueryListener` :

```
  kafkaConsumer.commitSync(topicPartitionMap);
```

Once the application is started it retrieves the offset map from Kafka and start the stream:

```
 reader = sparkSession
            .readStream()
            .format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", config.getKafkaBootStrapServers())
            .option("subscribe", "topic1")
            .option("max.poll.records", 1000)
            .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
            .option("startingOffsets", topicPartitionMap)
```

I store the `topic/partition/offset` with the data in the ORC files.

The data contain multiple duplicates of the events with exact `topic/partition/offset`.

How the stream should be configured to achieve exactly once processing ?

Comment: Why write Spark code instead of using an existing service that is used by other companies in Production? https://github.com/pinterest/secor

Comment: Multiple reasons 1. You need to manage schema in order to write ORC with Secor, 2. We have our own business logic 3. We already using Spark cluster.

Comment: You can also check this project : https://github.com/YotpoLtd/metorikku

Comment: Are you open to considering using a system other than Apache Spark?

Comment: I tested Secor And Kafka connect, those 2 are not suitable for me

Comment: Why and how are you committing offsets to Kafka after processing? by default spark structured streaming will store commits and offsets to checkpoints and How are you getting topicPartitionMap here ?

Comment: You can use `StreamingQueryListener`, see [here](https://gist.github.com/RonBarabash/ef85efdfc278b37793749278f04ae59f)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found out that those parameters should be set to `true`
`spark.streaming.driver.writeAheadLog.closeFileAfterWrite` and `spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.closeFileAfterWrite`

> Set this to 'true' when you want to use S3 for the metadata WAL

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

More details here:
https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-streaming/spark-streaming-configuration/read?fbclid=IwAR17x1AfTLH1pjq1QPkDsQT6DU4hgi7WNeIYUnw25Hvquoj-4yQU10R0GeM